# PLSQL user defined table types and joins

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, user-defined-types, varray

Let's say I have a user defined table type:

```
create or replace type SrcCodeTbl is table of varchar(20);
```

I have a procedure that has a parameter of this type:

```
create or replace procedure Blah.MyProc( srcCodesIN in SrcCodeTbl )
```

Can I use `srcCodesIn` in a select/join statement with another table within the procedure? Been trying to get it to work, and the compiler keeps reporting:

```
select distinct someVal into outVal 
from OtherTable ot, srcCodesIn sc 
where ot.ID = sc.column_val;

Error(28,22): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I'm sure its something simple with the syntax, I just haven't been able to figure it out. I did get something to work with a for-loop, but I'm interested if there's another way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT DISTINCT someVal 
INTO outVal 
FROM OtherTable ot, TABLE(srcCodesIn) sc 
WHERE ot.ID = sc.column_value
```

Comment: Yup, that'll work. I tried your original (before edit) answer, and that spit out a nebulous error message. Interesting that I need to cast a UDT table type to a table before using it as a... table. Gave you the answer since the other guy has a bazillion points already. 8)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it by simulating it in my local oracle so had to typecast it before converting it to table and then forgot to remove it afterwards :) Thanks for the points :)

Comment: Computers are all about precise definitions.    A UDT "table" is a TYPE not a TYPE as far as the data dictionary is concerned.  That's why you need to cast it in order to use it in a SQL statement.

Comment: which version of oracle are you guys using?